# Numbers has stopped showing up in Launchpad

Tags: macos, numbers, launchpad

Numbers has stopped showing up in Launchpad. How can I add it back?

Comment: Is it still installed in /Applications? Did you search through all pages of Launchpad?

Comment: Yes, it's still installed in /Applications and runs properly. I performed a search within Launchpad and it's nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type your application name in Launchpad's search box found near the top of every Launchpad screen. The icon for the desired App should be displayed on a new screen by itself - click and drag it to the desired location in Launchpad.

A commandline call may help as well - but be warned that it'll rebuild the Launchpad from scratch and will remove  any customizations you've added:

```
 rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db; killall Dock
```

Comment: The Launchpad rebuild did the trick. :)